# How to avoid generating Default primary key id in Golang (beego) model?

Tags: api, go, beego

I am trying to create a rest API. I have already a database. I want to create a struct linked to a database table. But when I run the project beego automatically creates an "id" primary key for the model registered. How to avoid this in beego?

My code example:

```
Model:
type Person struct {
    PersonId string `json:"person_id"`
    name string `json:"name"`
    email string `json:"email"`
}
```

**Problem: Encounter need a primary key field when using beego**
**It creates an id field in db table with default null value.**

**Note: person_id is the primary key in person table.**

Comment: What is the Database you are using? Some DBs automatically create primary keys, so your problem might be with the DB and not with beego.

Comment: I am using mysql database. It has already a primary key. I just created a model using those fields. Beego needs an Id in the struct and adds it on the database with default value 0.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want Beego’s ORM to have a different primary key, you should use this:

```golang
type Person struct {
    PersonId int64 `orm:"pk" json:"person_id"`
    name string `json:"name"`
    email string `json:"email"`
}
```

You can check the official documentation here in the primary key section:
[Beego Model Definition](https://beego.vip/docs/mvc/model/models.md)

This might be happening because when creating your table you have primary_key set to auto. Which is the default Beego behaviour.

Please check this article also:
https://developpaper.com/question/beegos-orm-gives-the-primary-key-value-every-update-delete-read/